# Error bloqueo por politicas CORS en conexion api hubspot con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

No me permite obtener los datos de hubspot mediante su api ya que me dice "has been blocked by CORS policy" como muestra la imagen. o sera porque lo estoy trabajando en localhost, y eso que tiengo agregado el "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El tema del CORS no se soluciona desde el cliente, debes configurar el servidor (el API en tu caso) si es que ese servicio lo permite. https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/data/serverless-functions/reference#cors

Comment: No puedes hacer una solicitud a la api de hubspot desde el cliente. https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/CORS-issue/m-p/304553